# htaccess and CURL login session

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, curl, authentication

When i login through htaccess loginbox i can navigate all files but when i login through curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$_SESSION['numerTelefonu'].":".$_SESSION['smsHaslo']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Then every time when i go to other file, browser ask about pass.
How to save login data in session?

Comment: cURL is stateless therefore you can not create a session using the `$_SESSION` global. Best you can do is work with cookies.

Comment: because your curl proxy here does not rewrite the links to tell the browser to access the files through the proxy, thus when you click on any of the links to any of the files, the browser will connect directly. you're trying to proxy this stuff, and when you say "when i go to other file", you mean through your browser that loaded the page served by php, right?